# The type or namespace name 'ScriptName' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) fix unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to reference another script that is attached to an object's parent. Here is the code I am trying to use

```
ScriptName sn = transform.parent.gameObject.GetComponent<Initializer>();
```

and here is the start of the script I am trying to reference

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class Initializer : MonoBehaviour
```

I'm not quite sure what the holdup is. I've tried googling but it doesn't really seem like anything is helping. What is the obvious fix that I'm somehow missing? Thanks in advance

Comment: Well just a wild guess .. but I guess after you blindly copy pasted that code from somewhere  you are supposed to replace `ScriptName sn` by the actual script name `Initializer xy = transform.parent.gameObject.GetComponent<Initializer>();` ^^ or simply use `var xy = ...` in the future ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to store the Initializer object in a "ScriptName". You probably wanted this:

```
Initializer initializer = transform.parent.GetComponent<Initializer>();
```

Note that you don't need to get the parent's GameObject to access the GetComponent() function.

You can also use the [GetComponentInParent()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentInParent.html) to get the component in any of its parents.

```
Initializer initializer = GetComponentInParent<Initializer>();
```